# tfjs-converter html javascript trouble importing class

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow

I'm trying to use the tensorflow.js API, and I want to import a saved python tensorflow model. I'm using [this github library](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) for the conversion. I've got these script imports in my html file:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.8.0"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
```

Then when I do this:

```
const model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
```

It says the class "loadFrozenModel is not defined".

In the github page it said to import using these:

```
import * as tfc from '@tensorflow/tfjs-core';
import {loadFrozenModel} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-converter';
```

When I do that, it gives:
" Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token * " 

and
 " Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token { " 
respectively. This error is even given when I install libraries using npm. Note: I'm using windows 10 and installed a third party npm. 

This are the two files in entirety if I missed out some important details: 
index.html :

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.8.0"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-core"></script>
    <script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Tiny TFJS example.<hr>
    <div id="micro_out_div"></div>
    <script src="index.js"> </script>
</body>
```

index.js :

```
async function myFirstTfjs() {
    const MODEL_URL = "PATH/TO/tensorflowjs_model.pb";
    const WEIGHTS_URL = 'PATH/TO/weights_manifest.json';
    const model = await loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
    const feed = {
        'op_to_restore': tf.tensor1d([0, 0, 0, 0])
    };
    document.getElementById('micro_out_div').innerText += model.execute(feed);
}

myFirstTfjs();
```

Answer (score 2):

By the time now, the problem is solved.
here's the final one.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.11.2"> </script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      const MODEL_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/tensorflowjs_model.pb';
      const WEIGHTS_URL = 'http://localhost:8000/weights_manifest.json';

      const model = tf.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
      console.log("model loaded");
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

  </body>
</html>
```

Do remember to add [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en-US) extension to disable CORS warning

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not seeing loadFrozenModel because the script is being loaded as a module. Also, `@tensorflow/tfjs` includes `@tensorflow/tfjs-core`, so you won't need to import both.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.9.0></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs-converter"></script>
</head>

<body>
    Tiny TFJS example.<hr>
    <div id="micro_out_div"></div>
</body>
<script src="index.js"> </script>
</html>
```

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function`

Answer (score 0):

If you are importing via script tags then you need to add tf_converter, as follows:

```
const model = await tf_converter.loadFrozenModel(MODEL_URL, WEIGHTS_URL);
```

Comment: Using chrome developer tools, the error I now get is: ReferenceError: tf_converter is not defined